# Vimeo API upload set title and description

Tags: php, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am trying to upload vimeo files to a vimeo account via their PHP API.

This is my code ( we upload first to server in $[FILES][tmp_name] then we upload that file to vimeo with their php api ) -

```
            $path = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
            $feedback = $vim->upload($path);
```

It works fine, just that I want it to be able to be uploaded with a title and a description.

Right now they are uploaded with the **Untitled** name.

There is no mention of title in their php api - https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php/blob/master/src/Vimeo/Vimeo.php

nor their api - https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

It's

```
$path = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
$feedback = $vim->upload($path);
$vim->request($feedback, array(
            'name' => 'ceva'
            ,'description' => 'alceva'
        ), 'PATCH');
```